# "android list targets" launches emulator

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to create new project using

```
cordova platform add android
```

But running this command launches android emulator and after I close the emulator I get the message

```
C:\devCenter\project\new_app>cordova platform add android
Creating android project...

C:\Users\think ahead\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: Please install Android target "android-19".
Hint: Run "android" from your command-line to open the SDK manager.
    at C:\Users\think ahead\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:174:19
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\think ahead\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\think ahead\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\think ahead\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:7
    at C:\Users\think ahead\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:574:44
    at flush (C:\Users\think ahead\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\think ahead\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
```

I have installed API-19 in SDK manager. So I checked check_reqs.js and found command that finds the API version number is

```
android list targets
```

When I execute this command, android emulator launches and dont get the list which is expected, here the output:

```
C:\devCenter\project\new_app>android list targets
OSALSockMap::init: sock_map=0x003F0000
start /SocketeQ/windowsandroid_root//system/bin/plogd ... 2528

C:\devCenter\project\new_app>start /SocketeQ/windowsandroid_root//system/bin/socketbinder ... 5648
add (socketbinder, 0) to sockmap ok
start /SocketeQ/windowsandroid_root//system/bin/servicemanager ... 10164
[ on init ]
[ on boot ]
[ service netd ]
[ service vold ]
[ service surfaceflinger ]
[ service ril-daemon ]
[ service zygote ]
[ service media ]
[ service drm ]
[ service installd ]
reference-ril requires: -p <tcp port> or -d /dev/tty_device
android-start was killed
app_process was killed
servicemanager was killed
socketbinder was killed
Could not open pipe: 2 second wait timed out.Could not open pipe: 2 second wait timed out.Could not open pipe: 2 second wait timed out.Cou
surfaceflinger was killed
instld was killed
no process 'alogd' was killed
plogd was killed
netd was killed
vold was killed
bootanimation was killed
rild was killed
no process 'drmserver' was killed
```

It seems like I have messed up my environment show how. Do anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, check if there is any other android development tool. Like in my case I had appcelerator installed which was in a way messing up the environment. Once removed whole thing worked like a charm. If there is any need to user multiple development platform, my suggestion is to use different partitions.